# Meaning of 法律のとおり

Tags: meaning

> 東京消防庁は、今も法律に違反しているマンションが３０２あるため、早く**法律のとおり**にするように言っています。
>   Even now, because there are 302 apartment blocks which are breaking the law, Tokyo fire department are telling people to quickly *decide on the law's street*.

I can't figure out at all what the fire department are telling people to do. I did a Google search for the phrase "法律のとおり" (in quotes) and only got 3 hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not とおり meaning "street". This とおり means "in accordance with". For example: 思ったとおり "as I thought", おっしゃったとおり "as you said", そのとおりです "that's the way it is", "that's right" (= そうです but a bit more formal), 次のとおり "as follows".

So 法律のとおりにする means "make it in accordance with the law", that is "bring it in line with the law"